# Libgdx font size

Tags: fonts, libgdx

Is it something like formula to calculate font size by given ascent height? And the same with specific width of the text? I want to draw string on the screen with specific height and width.

Comment: This is hard unless you are using a `monospaced` font (a font where each character takes the same width). In your case you probably need to know the size of each character, these are given in the `.fnt` file if you are using [Hiero](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Hiero) so you might want to look into that. The thing is, if you need exact numbers it's probably going to be a trial and error algorithm where you would try a specific size, measure it using `GlyphLayout` and go smaller if you need too.

Comment: Also,  you might want to supply additional detail like why you need this since there might be great solutions for laying out text and UI with Scene2D but I do not know of anything to create exact length text.

Comment: I don't know exactly what you want, but if you want to draw string on the screen I guess you should use the Label class, so you can call getHeight and getWidth functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here my code to fit given width, if text is too long, the label scale to fit given width

```
public class MyLabel extends Label {

private float customScale = 1; //default Scale if text's width < givenWidth
private GlyphLayout layout;
private boolean isWrap; //if wrap, ignore fit
private float defaultWidth;
protected boolean autoFit = false; //set true to auto fit when text changed

@Override
public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
    //draw background
    if(background != null)
        batch.draw(background, getX(), getY(), getOriginX(), getOriginY(), getWidth(), getHeight(), getScaleX(), getScaleY(), getRotation());
    else if(background9patch != null){
        background9patch.draw(batch, getX(), getY(), getOriginX(), getOriginY(), getWidth(), getHeight(), getScaleX(), getScaleY(), getRotation());
    }
    //draw text
    super.draw(batch, parentAlpha);
}

@Override
public void setText(CharSequence newText) {
    super.setText(newText);
    if(autoFit){
        float prefWidth = getPrefWidth();
        if(defaultWidth == 0 && getWidth() == 0){
            setWidth(prefWidth);
        } else {
            if (layout != null && !isWrap)
                if (getWidth() > 0) {
                    getStyle().font.getData().setScale(customScale);
                    layout.setText(getBitmapFontCache().getFont(), newText);
                    float textWidth = layout.width;
                    if (textWidth > getWidth())
                        setFontScale((getWidth() / textWidth));
                    else
                        setFontScale(customScale);
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate a font's size on screen using a [glyphlayout](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/GlyphLayout.html) and scale accordingly to fit it to your predefined width/height